# GET request with authorization headers (upgrade Rails-4.2 to Rails-5.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, doorkeeper

So we're upgrading our Rails app from Rails 4.2 to Rails 5.1. It all went well untill i have to upgrade our tests as well. We have an oauth_spec file for checking that everything works fine with our Auth process.

I'm currently changing the Rspec syntax so everything works fine but i'm really stuck with one of our tests. It keeps returning me 401-Unauthorized, and I think I've read everything I can find on StackOverflow about that.

Here's what our test looked like in 4.2:

```
it "grants access to a user's data when he sets an Authentication token as a request parameter" do
  data =
  {
    "grant_type" => "password",
    "password" => password,
    "username" => user.email
  }
  post('/oauth/token', data, {'HTTP_ACCEPT' => "application/json"})
  token = json["access_token"]
  get('/users/me', data, {'HTTP_ACCEPT' => "application/json", "Authorization" => "Bearer #{token}"})

  expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
  expect(json["email"]).to eq(user.email)
end
```

And here's what I got so far:

```
it "grants access to a user's data when he sets an Authentication token as a request parameter" do
  data =
  {
    "grant_type" => "password",
    "password" => password,
    "username" => user.email
  }
  post "/oauth/token", params: data
  token = json["access_token"]

  header = {"Authorization": "Bearer #{token}", "Accept": "application/json"}
  request.headers.merge!(header)
  get '/users/me'

  expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
  expect(json["email"]).to eq(user.email)
end
```

The first post request works just fine and give me my bearer. But next one break and I always get :

> Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_http_status(200) expected the response to have status code 200 but it was 401

Does anyone have a clue on what I could do to make this work?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you changed the syntax from `get('/users/me', data, {'HTTP_ACCEPT' => "application/json", "Authorization" => "Bearer #{token}"})` to adding headers manually to the `request` object and then `get '/users/me'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code:

```
get('/users/me', data, {'HTTP_ACCEPT' => "application/json", "Authorization" => "Bearer #{token}"})
```

Your new code:

```
header = {"Authorization": "Bearer #{token}", "Accept": "application/json"}
request.headers.merge!(header)
get '/users/me'
```

In the original code, you passed `data`, which is username and password, as parameters, while in the Rails 5 code you no longer pass that data. That *might* be one reason for the 401 error, but given the spec title, I don't think it is.

I recommend you just do:

```
get '/users/me', headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer #{token}", "Accept": "application/json"}
```